# c# search date in datagrid thru txtbox

Tags: c#

I have this form:

[image]

I managed to search IDs and text, and combobox, now I don't know how to search date?

```
if (txtIDGosta.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        long id;
        if (Int64.TryParse(txtIDGosta.Text, out id))
        {
            filter = "IDGosta = " + id.ToString();
        }
    }
```

This is how I search IDs(number)

```
if (txtRacunIzdao.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
            filter += " AND ";
            filter += "Izdao = " + txtRacunIzdao.Text;
        }
```

This is simple txtbox.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbTipRacuna.Text))
        {
            if (filter.Length > 0)
                filter += " AND ";
            filter += "IDTipRacuna = " + cmbTipRacuna.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }
```

This combobox.

How do I code to search date? (look at picture) to write in textbox '1.6.2011.' and to return me all fields with that date?

---

Ok, I tried this and it works:

```
if (txtDatIzd1.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        filter += " AND ";
        filter = "DatumIzdavanja = '1.6.2011'";
    }
```

Now I need to change it to read date from txtbox1, but it can't be txtbox1.text, won't read it, because its datatime type in ms access base.

Comment: When you write similar code to add a condition on the filter, is it producing zero rows? Is it producing the wrong rows?

Answer (score 0):

I would think you should be able to filter date similar to other fields.

```
if (txtDateBox.Text.Length > 0)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
            filter += " AND ";
    filter += "DateField = '" + txtDateBox.Text +"'";
}
```

Comment: Already tried that, but thanks. It is datetime field so i can't search it same as text fields.
i get cannot interpret token '.' at position 21 error

Comment: You can use txtDate.Text.Substring(0, txtDate.Text.Length - 1) instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of the ms access date format it takes. u have to covert your datetxt  in exactly ms Access format...
Try this out it might help you

```
if (txtDateBox.Text.Length > 0){  
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))         
{
 string mydate = DateTime.Parse(txtDateBox.Text).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
 filter += " AND ";    filter += "DateField = '" + mydate  +"'";}
 }
```

Comment: Sorry i have to add new answer since i don't have comment link on your.
@Syeda there seems to be problem with txtDateBox.Text.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'string.ToString(System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider'

Comment: @arslaa11: before using ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") parse your text value in Date.This error was coming due to converting string to datetimestring